# Difference between DL380 rails for different generations?

Tags: hp-proliant, rack, hardware

I just got an HP Proliant DL380 G5 server (it's actually Cisco branded, but I don't think that matters), without the rack rails. I'm trying to learn some server architecture and use it as a basic server. I am looking for some rails to mount it in my rack.

What are the differences of the rails between generations? I see a lot of G6 rails with the cable management arm for sale; is it backward compatible with the G5? Or, do I need to seek out a G5 rail specifically?

If the differences are minor enough, could I simply mod the rails? (e.g. drill my own holes).

Comment: There are actually a number of different rails and rail kits for that model of HP.  What's the part number of the rails in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP DL380 Rail Kits:

G1 327310-001
G2 228894-B21
G3 300605-001
G4 359254-001
G5 359254-001
G6 574765-001
G7 616992 001
G8 663480-B21 (LFF) or 663478-B21 (SFF)

Note: only G4 and G5 are the same.

Comment: I'd highly recommend against drilling holes in the chassis. Also, local resellers typically haves piles of rails sitting around they'd love to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

I would just pick up a third-party rail kit at this point. Otherwise, [get the G5 specific rails from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-359254-001-ProLiant-DL380-G4-G5-DL385-G1-G2-G5-2U-Rackmount-Rails-Rail-Kit-/370640590722?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item564be69782). They are not interchangeable between recent generations.

See: http://www.racksolutions.com/hp